# Order of direct product in definition of a tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, tensors

The following comes from the Wikipedia page on Abstract Index Notation and is consistent with my understanding.

> A general homogeneous tensor is an element of a tensor product of copies of $V$ and $V^{*}$, such as
>
> $V\otimes V^{*}\otimes V^{*}\otimes V\otimes V^{*}$
>
> Label each factor in this tensor product with a Latin letter in a raised position for each contravariant $V$ factor, and in a lowered position for each covariant $V^{*}$ position. In this way, write the product as
>
> $V^{a}V_{b}V_{c}V^{d}V_{e}$
> or, simply
>
> ${{{V^{a}}_{bc}}^{d}}_{e}$
> The last two expressions denote the same object as the first. Tensors of this type are denoted using similar notation, for example:
>
> ${{{h^{a}}_{bc}}^{d}}_{e}\in {{{V^{a}}_{bc}}^{d}}_{e}=V\otimes V^{*}\otimes V^{*}\otimes V\otimes V^{*}$

Now this comes from the section on the Wikipedia page on Tensors about viewing tensors as multilinear maps

> One approach that is common in differential geometry is to define tensors relative to a fixed (finite-dimensional) vector space V, which is usually taken to be a particular vector space of some geometrical significance like the tangent space to a manifold.[5] In this approach, a type (p, q) tensor T is defined as a multilinear map,
>
> $$T:\underbrace {V^{*}\times \dots \times V^{*}} _{p{\text{ copies}}}\times \underbrace {V\times \dots \times V} _{q{\text{ copies}}}\rightarrow \mathbf {R}$$
> where V∗ is the corresponding dual space of covectors, which is linear in each of its arguments. The above assumes V is a vector space over the real numbers, ℝ. More generally, V can be taken over any field F (e.g. the complex numbers), with F replacing ℝ as the codomain of the multilinear maps.

Now my question is, why when they are defined as multilinear maps from the direct product of the space ordered with the $p$ covariant spaces first and then the $q$ contravariant spaces, but when we look at the space the tensors live in in the first definition, it is ordered in the order of the abstract indices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ordering of the indices is arbitrary. It’s more convenient, with general $p$ and $q$ to write $V^{*p}\times V^q$, isn’t it? How are you going denote it in general in a concise, understandable manner?

Comment: Another source of confusion is the difference between the specification of the arguments you feed the tensor and the tensor itself. The *set* of all $(q+p)$-linear functions on $V^q\times (V^*)^p$ is denoted by $(V^*)^q\otimes V^p=\mathfrak{F}^p_q$. Notice the "switch" of $p$ and $q$. Any element of $\mathfrak{F}^p_q$ is a type $(p,q)$ tensor; in particular, elements of $\mathfrak{F}^1_0=V$ and $\mathfrak{F}^0_1=V^*$ are respectively type $(1,0)$ and type $(0,1)$ tensors (vectors, covectors).

Comment: Thank you both very much. @TedShifrin does this mean that it does not matter the order of the indices for a tensor written in abstract index notation? For example, is ${{R_{a}}^{b}}_{cd}$ the same as ${R^{b}}_{acd}$?

Comment: @Jake Yeah, as long as you're consistent, it makes absolutely no difference. Some authors tend to write $T_a^{\ \,b}$ instead of $T_a^b$ just to remind readers of the usual matrix row/column convention, with column following row.